# sql sort statement not working correctly

Tags: sql

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) as total FROM user GROUP BY country ASC
```

I am using this statement to display records from my table and display them. It displays the records on the basis of country and sorts them. I need to sort the records on the basis of total . and display them accordingly. i.e. I want to display the count in DESC order.

Comment: i was trying to sort from groyp by :( ,

Comment: This question is quite understandable. The OP has also done some homework and posted the attempted query. The question is understandable to the extent that an answer has been posted. The answer (without any further modifications) has worked for the OP. I do not see why the question needs to be down-voted so much.

Comment: @JosephB What they posted doesn't even run. They just seem to have stuck an `asc` in randomly and hoped it would work by magic. A brief glance at the SQL grammar would show the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) as total 
FROM user 
GROUP BY country 
order by total desc
```